# How do I calculate the vector flux outgoing a domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I need to calculate the flux $F(x,y,z)=(x+yz,y+xz,z+xy)$ outgoing from the boundary $\vartheta D$ of :

$D = ${$(x,y,z)\in R^3 : z \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}  $    ,   $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4 $}

Comment: This is very nice with the divergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) since your $\nabla \cdot F$ is constant. Just multiply it by the volume of $D$.

Comment: How do I calculate the volume D ?